# Adjust camera focus in ARKit

Tags: swift, camera, arkit

I want to adjust the device's **physical camera** focus while in augmented reality. (I'm not talking about the `SCNCamera` object.)
In an [Apple Dev forum post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/78954), I've read that autofocus would interfere with ARKit's object detection, which makes sense to me.

Now, I'm working on an app where the users will be close to the object they're looking at. The focus the camera has by default makes everything look very blurry when closer to an object than around 10cm.

Can I adjust the camera's focus before initializing the scene, or preferably while in the scene?

---

*20.01.2018*
Apparently, there's still no solution to this problem. You can read more about this at [this reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/761r2u/is_it_just_me_or_do_all_arkit_apps_have_blurry/) and [this developer forum post](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/78954) for private API workarounds and other (non-helping) info.

---

*25.01.2018*
@AlexanderVasenin provided a useful update pointing to Apple's documentation. It shows that `ARKit` will be able to support not just focusing, but also **autofocusing** as of iOS 11.3.
See my usage sample below.

Comment: have you managed to find any solution for this one ?

Comment: Nope. The post keeps getting upvoted but no one has answered or even commented so far so I'm guessing there's no solution at this point.

Comment: Good news everyone: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/2942262-isautofocusenabled

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As [stated by Alexander](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46145637/adjust-camera-focus-in-arkit/48436998#answer-48392885), iOS 11.3 brings autofocus to ARKit.
The [corresponding documentation site](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/2942262-isautofocusenabled) shows how it is declared:

```
var isAutoFocusEnabled: Bool { get set }
```

You can access it this way:

```swift
var configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.isAutoFocusEnabled = true // or false
```

However, as it is `true` by default, you should not even have to set it manually, unless you chose to opt out.

Answer (score 3):

UPDATE: Starting from iOS 11.3 ARKit supports autofocusing, and it's enabled by default ([more info](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arworldtrackingconfiguration/2942262-isautofocusenabled)). Manual focusing still aren't available.

---

Prior to iOS 11.3 ARKit did not supported neither manual focus adjust nor autofocusing.

Here is Apple's reply on the subject (Oct 2017):

> ARKit does not run with autofocus enabled as it may adversely affect plane detection. There is an existing feature request to support autofocus and no need to file additional requests. Any other focus discrepancies should be filed as bug reports. Be sure to include the device model and OS version. ([source](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/78954))

There is [another thread](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/87909) on Apple forums where a developer claims he was able to adjust autofocus by calling `AVCaptureDevice.setFocusModeLocked(lensPosition:completionHandler:)` method on **private** `AVCaptureDevice` used by ARKit and it appears it's not affecting tracking. Though [the method](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avcapturedevice/1624617-setfocusmodelocked) itself is public, the ARKit's `AVCaptureDevice` is not, so using this hack in production would most likely result in App Store rejection.

Comment: Umm thanks? I mean 1) my question is not about autofocus and 2) I have already linked that workaround.

Comment: @LinusGeffarth I just summarized your findings in an answer to make it easier for other devs. You can do it yourself if you like to.

Comment: Thanks for keeping us posted!

Answer (score 0):

```
    if #available(iOS 16.0, *) {
        // This property is nil on devices that aren’t equiped with an ultra-wide camera.
        if let device = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration.configurableCaptureDeviceForPrimaryCamera {
            do {
                try device.lockForConfiguration ()
                
                // configuration your focus mode 
                // you need to change  ARWorldTrackingConfiguration().isAutoFocusEnabled at the same time
                
                device.unlockForConfiguration ()
            } catch {
                
            }
        }
    } else {
        // Fallback on earlier versions
    }
```

Use `configurableCaptureDeviceForPrimaryCamera` method, and this is only  available after iOS 16 or later.

[Documentation
/
ARKit
/
Configuration Objects
/
ARConfiguration
/
configurableCaptureDeviceForPrimaryCamera](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/arkit/arconfiguration/3930045-configurablecapturedeviceforprim?changes=__6&language=objc)